# Set database value after a certain date has passed

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with variables I want to change depending on the date. The events in the database have dates. After this date I would like to set a variable 'past' to true. Meaning, the event has past. How can I approach this with php or is this something that needs to be added to the database itself (using phpMyAdmin) ?

Comment: Why is that necessary? You could only save a date and the client could compare against the date and mark it (internally!) as done.

Comment: hmm not sure how thats done ... how would I compare it (how would the client know the date) im assuming client = database?

Comment: Seems like you're asking how to solve a solution the hard way.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you only ask questions regarding your current code. We do not invent nor write code for you.

Comment: @jens1o sorry not asking for code, just an explanation

Comment: Well, then stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask such a question. :/

Answer (score 0):

Naturally, you first need code that does the actual update. This could very well be a PHP script, but you probably won't want to embed it into a web page, but to run it from the command line (see below).

Secondly, you need to execute that code on a regular basis so every update is done within a guaranteed time span after the event has passed. To execute scripts or other code regularly, you can use `cron` (if you are on Linux) and similar mechanisms.

If you need to make sure that the updates are done *as fast as possible* after the respective event has passed, you will need to write a full-blown daemon which runs in the background and does its checks 10 times per second, for example, or (instead of polling) uses appropriately programmed one-shot timers.

If you insist on writing the script in PHP and don't want to run it from the command line (as required by `cron` for example), you still can embed your code into a web page as usual and then use tools like `wget` or `curl` in conjunction with `cron` to retrieve that web page and get your code executed regularly.